# how to handle multiple push notifications in android

Tags: android, push-notification

When one push notifications is arrived, if user is not available to see the notification. Meanwhile he got another notification and got updated with previous notifications. But it should not update with latest one. I need to get all notifications separately to handle them. Is it possible?

Please help over this.

http://chunkiat90.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-multiple-notification-handling.html

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set an unique id to your notifications and you'll always get a new notification without update previous

**upd:**
Juust add an int field like a `notId`, and increase it every time you send a notification

Comment: This is not good.what happen if user receives 100 messages.I assume good way is to use notification stack.

Comment: @preethi i've updated my answer, let me know if y've any troubles with that

Answer (score 1):

The correct field to set (as of plugin version v2.4.0) is `notId` (not `notifiyId`)
This field name is hard coded in the plugin. The list of available fields you can use are:

- `message`
- `msgcnt`
- `title`
- `notId`