# How to handle multiple push notification of pushplugin

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using pushplugin in my cordova app for android. There is no problem for single message. While sending multiple message when app is minimized, I see only the last notification which replaces the previous notifications.

I followed https://github.com/manjeshpv/PushPlugin/commit/cdd1f56ef7a6a2033a196546cd6b946dc17044ae
https://github.com/manjeshpv/PushPlugin/commit/d073ed105aafb1f8793ea3c9a2b5b04e8293f507

None of these working for me.
I'm also using notId in payload. In my php file:

```
$message = '{"conversation":"'.$message.'", "phoneNumber":"'.$phoneNumber.'", "file":"text", "notId":"'.time().'"}';
```

There would have few similar questions but the problem was not solved there.
[how to handle multiple push notifications in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581130/how-to-handle-multiple-push-notifications-in-android)

Comment: what you have done? share your code here

Comment: Solved myself.

    $message = '{"conversation":"'.$message.'", "phoneNumber":"'.$phoneNumber.'"}';

In php curl:

    $field = array(
                'registration_ids' => array($registatoin_id),
                'data' => array( 'message' => $message, 'title'=>'kwikieText', 'msgcnt'=>'3', 'notId'=>''.time() ),
            );
`'notId'` must be added to 'data' field not the `$message` variable.

Comment: You should add your answer and mark it as solved

Answer (score 3):

The answer in your linked question is wrong. 
The correct field to add is `notId` (not `notificationID`)
This will separate your notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Solved myself

```
$message = '{"conversation":"'.$message.'", phoneNumber":"'.$phoneNumber.'"}';
```

In php curl:

```
$field = array( 'registration_ids' => array($registatoin_id), 'data' => array( 'message' => $message, 'title'=>'kwikieText', 'msgcnt'=>'3', 'notId'=>''.time() ), );
```

`notId` must be added to 'data' field not the $message variable